# after adding @addTagHelper to the *.cshtml file. error 500 is shown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

When I Use

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

in My .cshtml file it causes error 500. but it's work in another ViewComponent

Comment: generally that would go in _ViewImports.cshtml then you don't need to add it in any views

Comment: error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: When i add in _ViewImports.cshtml it's same error

Comment: That is not the real error. See if you can get the real one from the `eventvwr`.

Comment: Are you using nightly builds?

Comment: You can get the real error by adding the Diagnostics package and then doing app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in your Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

which version? please give us more information.
if you are using rc1-update1 use 
        @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure out the exact cause. However, changing  the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers" depencency in my json file from "6.0.0-betaX" to "6.0.0-rc1-final" fixed the issue. Make sure to restore packages after this change.

Also: as suggested the @TagHelper statement should go to your _viewImports.cshtml file.