# Website isn't working after adding TagHelper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, assemblies, tag-helpers

after adding this line at the top of the _Layout.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

The website is showing blank page when running.

what could be the problem and what can I do ?

Comment: You usually add that to _ViewImports.cshtml which is inherited by all other views. Also remember to install the package for taghelper

Comment: already installed the packages through project.json, and I tried to put that in _ViewImports.chhtml but it doesn't change the problem

Comment: have you checked dev tools for any errors?

Comment: The VS doesn't display any errors. what's dev tools ?

Comment: browser's dev tools. F12 => console tab

Comment: * Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
* Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).   That's what chrome showing

Comment: have a look at this see if you can add diagnostic package as per comments, if upgrading to final doesnt help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360005/after-adding-addtaghelper-to-the-cshtml-file-error-500-is-shown and here http://themagicsoftware.com/blog/category/asp-net-5-0

Comment: The first solution from the first link did it! I used an older version for the TagHelpers